# Qt c++ Pong ball direction

Tags: c++, qt, pong

c++, qt

And now I am programming pong game's ball direction part.

For me my idea looks alright, but it doesn't work well.

My idea is this.

par_x, par_y are present ball position.
pre_x, pre_y are previous ball position.

This code is ball moving part.

Please, let me know my wrong idea.
I don't know where is wrong.

It build well, but the ball doesn't bounce right direction. It moves to other way or stick on boundary.

This code is mainwindow.h and mainwindow.cpp

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPalette>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtEvents>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFocusFrame>
#include <QMap>
#include <QString>
#include <QThread>
#include <math.h>
#include <QVector>

class Ball: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    int x, y;
    int pre_x, pre_y;
    int par_x, par_y;

public:
    Ball(){x=380; y=490;}
    int get_x();
    int get_y();
    void set_x(int x);
    void set_y(int y);
    void set_posx(int x, int oper);
    void set_posy(int y, int oper);
    void oper_switch(int flag);
    void direction(int now);
    QVector <int> vector_x;
    QVector <int> vector_y;
    QVector <int> :: iterator it;

protected:
    void run();

signals:
    int sig();

};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QImage      *img_bar, *img_ball, *img_background, *img_GameBack;
    QPixmap     *buf_bar, *buf_ball, *buf_background, *buf_GameBack ;
    QLabel      *lbl_bar, *lbl_ball, *lbl_background, *lbl_GameBack ;
    QWidget     *backWidget;
    Ball        *ball;
    QPushButton *btn[3];


private slots:
    void        btn_click();
    void        ball_move();

protected:
    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    virtual void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H






 #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

int bar_x = 350;    // Bar
const int bar_y = 500;
int btn_y = 350;  // Button position
int key_flag = 0;
int oper_flag = 0;
int bar_ball = 0;
int t = 0;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
       ball = new Ball();
       img_background = new QImage();
       buf_background = new QPixmap();

       if(img_background->load("C://Users//user//Documents//BreaOut//Background.png"))
       {
           *buf_background = QPixmap::fromImage(*img_background);
           *buf_background = buf_background->scaled(800,600);    
       }
       else
       {
          qDebug("Image can't find.");
       }

      lbl_background = new QLabel(this);
      lbl_background->setPixmap(*buf_background);
      lbl_background->resize(buf_background->width(),buf_background->height()); 
      lbl_background->move(0,0);
      lbl_background->show();

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0 :
            {
                btn[i] = new QPushButton(QString("Game Start").arg(i), this);
                break;
            }
            case 1 :
            {
                btn[i] = new QPushButton(QString("How to play game?").arg(i), this);
                break;
            }
        }
        btn[i] -> setGeometry(325, btn_y, 150, 40);
        btn_y += 50;
    }

    connect(btn[0], SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(btn_click()));



     img_GameBack = new QImage();
     buf_GameBack = new QPixmap();

     if(img_GameBack->load("C://Users//user//Documents//BreaOut//GameBack.png"))
     {
         *buf_GameBack = QPixmap::fromImage(*img_GameBack);
         *buf_GameBack = buf_GameBack->scaled(800,600);    // 이미지 크기 조정
     }
     else
     {
        qDebug("Image can't find.");
     }

    lbl_GameBack = new QLabel(this);
    lbl_GameBack->setPixmap(*buf_GameBack);
    lbl_GameBack->resize(buf_GameBack->width(),buf_GameBack->height());
    lbl_GameBack->move(0,0);
    lbl_GameBack->setVisible(false);


        /*! 바 이미지 삽입*/
        img_bar = new QImage();
        buf_bar = new QPixmap();

        if(img_bar->load("C://Users//user//Documents//BreaOut//bar.png"))
        {
            *buf_bar = QPixmap::fromImage(*img_bar);
            *buf_bar = buf_bar->scaled(80,18);    // 이미지 크기 조정
        }
        else
        {
           qDebug("Image can't find.");
        }

       lbl_bar = new QLabel(this);
       lbl_bar->setPixmap(*buf_bar);
       lbl_bar->resize(buf_bar->width(),buf_bar->height()); 
           lbl_bar->move(bar_x, bar_y);
       //    lbl_bar->show();
           lbl_bar->setVisible(false);


    img_ball = new QImage();
    buf_ball = new QPixmap();

    if(img_ball->load("C://Users//user//Documents//BreaOut//Ball.png"))
    {
        *buf_ball = QPixmap::fromImage(*img_ball);
        *buf_ball = buf_ball->scaled(12,12);    // 이미지 크기 조정
    }
    else
    {
         qDebug("Image can't find.");
    }

    lbl_ball = new QLabel(this);

    lbl_ball->setVisible(false); connect(ball, SIGNAL(sig()), this, SLOT(ball_move()));
    lbl_ball->setPixmap(*buf_ball);
    lbl_ball->resize(buf_ball->width(),buf_ball->height()); 
    lbl_ball->move(ball->get_x(), ball->get_y());
    lbl_ball->show();
    lbl_ball->setVisible(false);

   connect(ball, SIGNAL(sig()), this, SLOT(ball_move()));

    QString brk1, brk2, brk3;
    brk1 = "X://parkjh688//Breakout//Brick1.png";
    brk2 = "X://parkjh688//Breakout//Brick2.png";
    brk3 = "X://parkjh688//Breakout//Brick3.png";

   /* QMap<QString, QMap<int, int> > m1 = { {brk1,1,1}, {brk1,1,1}, {brk1,1,1}, {brk1,1,1}, {brk1,1,1}, {brk1,1,1},
                                          {brk2,1,1}, {brk2,1,1}, {brk2,1,1}, {brk2,1,1}, {brk2,1,1}, {brk2,1,1},
                                          {brk3,1,1}, {brk3,1,1}, {brk3,1,1}, {brk3,1,1}, {brk3,1,1}, {brk3,1,1}};

    QMap<QString, QMap<int, int> > :: iterator it1;
    QMap<int, int> :: iterator it2;



    for(it1=m.begin(); it1 != m.end() ; it1++)
    {

    }*/


  //  for( it1 = m.begin() ; it1 != m.end() ; it1++)



    setWindowTitle("BreakOut");
    setFixedSize(800, 600);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::btn_click()
{
    lbl_background->setVisible(false);
    lbl_GameBack->setVisible(true);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        btn[i]->setVisible(false);
    }

    lbl_bar->setVisible(true);
    lbl_ball->setVisible(true);
    key_flag = 1;
}
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{

    Q_UNUSED(event);

    qDebug("Key Press Event.");


   if(key_flag == 1){

        switch(event->key())
        {
        case Qt::Key_A: // A가 눌렸을 때
            if( bar_x > 0)
            {
                bar_x -=20;                  // lbl_bar를 움직이기 위한 좌표 변경
                qDebug() << bar_x;
                if(bar_ball == 0)
                {
                    ball->set_posx(20,1);
                    lbl_ball->move(ball->get_x(),ball->get_y());   
                    lbl_bar->move(bar_x,bar_y);   
                }
                    lbl_bar->move(bar_x,bar_y);  
            }
            lbl_bar->show();
            break;

        case Qt::Key_D: // D가 눌렸을 때
            if( bar_x < 720)
            {
                bar_x+=20;
                if(bar_ball == 0)
                {
                    ball->set_posx(20,0);
                    lbl_ball->move(ball->get_x(),ball->get_y());   
                    lbl_bar->move(bar_x,bar_y);
                }
                    lbl_bar->move(bar_x,bar_y);
            }
            lbl_bar->show(); break;
            break;

        case Qt::Key_W:
             ball->start();
             bar_ball = 1;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent*event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
}

void MainWindow::ball_move()
{
    lbl_ball->move(ball->get_x(), ball->get_y());
    lbl_ball->show();
}

int Ball::get_x(){ return x; }

int Ball::get_y(){ return y; }

/* oper 0 : +=
 * oper 1 : -= */
void Ball::set_posx(int x, int oper)
{
    switch(oper)
    {
    case 0: this->x += x; break;

    case 1: this->x -= x; break;
    }
}

void Ball::set_posy(int y, int oper)
{
    switch(oper)
    {
    case 0: this->y += y; break;
    case 1: this->y -= y; break;
    }
}

void Ball::run()
{
    bool stop = false;
    int now = 0;
    int lock = 1;

    while(!stop)
    {
        vector_x.push_back(x);
        vector_y.push_back(y);

      /*  for(it = vector_x.begin(); it != vector_x.end(); it++)
                qDebug() << "x:" << (*it);

        for(it = vector_y.begin(); it != vector_y.end(); it++)
                qDebug() << "Y:" << (*it);*/

       if(y < 5)
       {
         //  oper_flag = 1;
         //  oper_switch(oper_flag);

          now = 3;

          it = vector_x.end();
          it -= 2;
          pre_x = (*it);
          par_x = x;
        //  qDebug() << "pre_x: " << pre_x;
        //  qDebug() << "X    : " << x;

          it = vector_y.end();
          it -= 2;
          pre_y = (*it);
          par_y = y;
        //  qDebug() << "pre_y: " << pre_y;
        //   qDebug() << "Y    : " << y;
       }
       else if( ((bar_x < x) && (x < bar_x+80)) &&
                                ((bar_y < y) && (y < bar_y+30)) )
       {
            //oper_flag = 0;
           now = 4;

           it = vector_x.end();
           it -= 2;
           pre_x = (*it);
           par_x = x;
           qDebug() << "pre_x: " << pre_x;
           qDebug() << "X    : " << x;

           it = vector_y.end();
           it -= 2;
           pre_y = (*it);
           par_y = y;
           qDebug() << "pre_y: " << pre_y;
           qDebug() << "Y    : " << y;

         qDebug() << "Bar Collision.";
       }
       else if(x > 785)
       {
           //oper_flag = 3;
           now = 2;

           it = vector_x.end();
           it -= 2;
           pre_x = (*it);
           par_x = x;
           qDebug() << "pre_x: " << pre_x;
           qDebug() << "X    : " << x;

           it = vector_y.end();
           it -= 2;
           pre_y = (*it);
           par_y = y;
           qDebug() << "pre_y: " << pre_y;
           qDebug() << "Y    : " << y;
       }
       else if(x < 0)
       {
           //oper_flag = 3;
           now = 1;

           it = vector_x.end();
           it -= 2;
           pre_x = (*it);
           par_x = x;
           qDebug() << "pre_x: " << pre_x;
           qDebug() << "X    : " << x;

           it = vector_y.end();
           it -= 2;
           pre_y = (*it);
           par_y = y;
           qDebug() << "pre_y: " << pre_y;
           qDebug() << "Y    : " << y;
           lock = 0;
       }
       else if( y > 580)
       {
                stop = true;
                qDebug() << "Thread Finish.";
       }
        //oper_switch(oper_flag);
       direction(now);
       sig();
        msleep(20);
    }
}

void Ball::set_x(int x) { this->x = x;  }

void Ball::set_y(int y) { this->y = y; }

void Ball::direction(int now)
{
    float theta, r;

    theta = atan2( (float)(par_y-pre_y), (float)(par_x-pre_x) ) *180 / 3.1415f;


    qDebug() << r;

    if(now == 0)
    {
        x += 2;
        y -= 5;
    }
    else if(now == 1)
    {
        if( (par_x<pre_x) && (par_y<pre_y) )
        {
            x += sin(theta)*10;
            y -= cos(theta)*10;
        }
        else if( (par_x<pre_x) && (par_y>pre_y) )
        {
            x += sin(theta)*3;
            y += cos(theta)*3;
        }
    }
    else if(now == 2)
    {

       // vector_x.clear();
       // vector_y.clear();

        if( (par_x>pre_x) && (par_y>pre_y) )   // |
        {                                     // \/
            x -= sin(theta)*10;
            y += cos(theta)*10;
        }
        else if( (par_x>pre_x) && (par_y<pre_y) )
        {
            x -= sin(theta)*10;
            y -= cos(theta)*10;
        }
    }
    else if(now == 3)
    {

        if( (par_x>pre_x) && (par_y<pre_y) )    // ->
        {
            x += cos(theta)*10;
            y += sin(theta)*10;
        }
        else if( (par_x<pre_x) && (par_y<pre_y))    // <-
        {
            x -= cos(theta)*10;
            y += sin(theta)*10;
        }

    }
    else // now == 4
    {
     //   vector_x.clear();
     //   vector_y.clear();

        if( (par_x>pre_x) && (par_y>pre_y) ) // ->
        {
            x += cos(theta)*10;
            y -= sin(theta)*10;
        }
        else if( (par_x<pre_x) && (par_y>pre_y) )
        {
            x -= cos(theta)*10;
            y -= sin(theta)*10;
        }
    }

}

/*
void Ball::oper_switch(int flag)
{
    float theta;

    it = vector_x.end();
    it -= 2;
    qDebug() << (*it);

    pre_x = (*it);

    it = vector_y.end();
    //pre_y = vector_y.at(it--);

    // theta = atan2( (float)(y-pre_y), (float)(x-pre_x) ) *180 / 3.1415f;

    switch(flag)
    {
    case 0:
        y -= 2, x += 2;
        break;
    case 1:
        y += 2; x += 2;
        theta = atan2( (float)(y-pre_y), (float)(x-pre_x) ) *180 / 3.1415f;
        x += cos(theta);
        y -= sin(theta);
        break;
    case 3:
        y -= 2; x-=2; break;
    }
}*/
```

[ball direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e67G5.jpg)

Comment: 1) You have not told us how the result is wrong, 2) you have not given us enough information to reproduce the error, 3) you have not told us whether you have solved the one-dimensional case before this attempt on the two-dimensional case.

Comment: Ah sorry, It build well, but the ball doesn't bounce right direction. It moves to other way or stick on boundary.

Comment: If the ball is just bouncing in mirror-like fashion off surfaces that are parallel to the X and Y axes, consider defining ball position as a QVector2D and ball velocity (speed + direction) as a QVector2D, and then change the +/- sign on the x or y component of the velocity QVector2D when the ball collides with a surface. For collisions with a moving paddle you can impart a new direction and speed on the ball by adding (ballVelocity + factor * paddleVelocity). If you use vectors then I think the code would be easier to understand. Also, ADD MEANINGFUL COMMENTS as Beta suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how well this is going to answer your question, but I can't really get a good grasp on what you're trying to do here because there aren't any comments in your code, nor can I implicitly run your code because I'll need all the libraries and whatever that you're using and that's a lil too much work for me right now.

However, have you considered reworking your entire ball movement from a different perspective? It seems like you are doing a lot of unecessary work to move that ball, why don't you just treat it like a point on a Cartesian grid system? For instance:

```
double x; //position of ball on x axis, global variable
double y; //position of ball on y axis, global variable
double speed = 1; //speed of ball, global variable

void move()
{
    //the operation below will move the ball in a 45 degree angle to the
    //top-right for every drawn frame
    x += speed;
    y += speed;
}
```

Also, you can change the direction of the ball in this manner as well, just simply change the increment values for x and y depending on the current quadrant the ball is traveling towards. For instance, the ball would be traveling in quadrant 1 in the example, and to send it to the bottom-left it would be in the direction of quadrant 3. Just make sure to keep the sum of speed for both x and y the same number, or else the ball will speed up/slow down depending on the magnitude of the angle.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it is quite different. For moving the ball, I should think speed and and direction.

Comment: You can get direction out of this. You just have to change the value of speed. You can make the value larger, which will make the ball go faster. Also, you could have two doubles to give different speed on the x or y axis. For instance `x += speedX; y += speedY;`. You just have to make sure that the sum of speedX and speedY are always the same.

Comment: Is degree always 45?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, just change the values, assign different values to each double. For instance: `speedX = 1.5; speedY = .5;`

Comment: Qt has built-in vector types: QVector2D, QVector3D, QVector4D. These can be used for position and velocity. There are also matrix classes that are handy for transformations. Better to use these built-in types than to have a plethora of variables to accomplish the same thing. In my comment above I suggested defining position as one QVector2D and velocity as a second QVector2D. Add those two vectors together at each increment of time to yield the new position; after a collision, simply change the sign of the X or Y component of the velocity vector--this will work regardless of collision angle.